# how to load html in SL4 Child window?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

in this case , without using third party controls, load Html content in silverlight child window.(SL-4 InBrowser Application)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way in Silverlight 4 to do this in browser.  The only way to do this in browser is to use javascript interop.  You have to run the Silverlight app in Windowless mode, and create a div on the web page that is placed on top of the Silverlight application.  You then have to move that div around based on the current coordinates of the Silverlight windows using javascript interop.  This is not entirely trivial.  Good luck.